# Malicious vbs script only opens a GET HTTPS connection

Tags: tls

Today we received a malicious vbs script in our mailbox (attachment was a zip containing the script).

Underneath you can find the source (note: domain changed due to not wanting to spread malware, but the parameters are still the same).

```
Dim ProxyOn, ProxyServer, ProxyOverride
Dim h, hh, s, u

Set s = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")

u = "https://example.com/?rid%3DVGX0Ipd&pad%3DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
u = Replace(u, "%3D", "=")

On Error Resume Next

ProxyOn = s.RegRead("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" & "ProxyEnable")
ProxyServer = s.RegRead("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" & "ProxyServer")

Set h =  CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Set hh = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

If ProxyOn = 1 Then
    h.SetProxy 2, ProxyServer
End If

hh.SetProxy 1, ProxyServer

On Error Resume Next

h.Open "GET", u, False
h.SetTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000
h.Send

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  On Error Resume Next
  hh.Open "GET", u, False
  hh.SetTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000
  hh.Send
End If

WScript.Sleep 2000
WScript.Echo "Installation completed."
```

To me it does not seem to do much, it reads proxy setting (to avoid firewall?) and issues a GET command to the (malicious) URL, but doesn't do anything with the response.

Of course we did not try running.

What exactly does this code try to do?

EDIT:
Today we received confirmation that this is part of a campaign about cyber security in the company! The analysis in the answer is indeed correct.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your assessment seems accurate.  I see 2 possible options:

1. This is a reconnaissance probe to see if someone will open the attachments.
2. This attack was poorly executed, and you were sent an unfinished script.

I'm currently leaning towards the second explanation.  There is no reason to echo any output in a dropper, let alone something as suspicious as "Installation completed."